# Problems linking ACE in VC++

Tags: visual-c++, ace

I've built ACE.dll and ACE.lib of the ACE library. But when I link it to my program, I get several errors like

> Error 2 error LNK2019: unresolved
>   external symbol "void * __cdecl
>   ACE_OS::memcpy(void *,void const
>   *,unsigned int)" (?memcpy@ACE_OS@@YAPAXPAXPBXI@Z)
>   referenced in function "public: void
>   __thiscall ACE_String_Base::set(char const
>   *,unsigned int,bool)" (?set@?$ACE_String_Base@D@@QAEXPBDI_N@Z)
>   client_handler.obj Server
>
> Error 3 error LNK2001: unresolved
>   external symbol "void * __cdecl
>   ACE_OS::memcpy(void *,void const
>   *,unsigned int)" (?memcpy@ACE_OS@@YAPAXPAXPBXI@Z)
>   Server.obj

I've set include paths,lib paths, lib dependencies etc etc. I dont know what I'm missing :(

Comment: How do you add ACE.lib to link?

Comment: in the project properties > linker > input > additional dep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The linker is unable to find a definition for `ACE_OS::memcpy`. Check the documentation and see if you need to provide a suitable definition or not (or if there is one in the sample, if any samples are present at all).

This could also be because you've not defined a platform specific macro that would enable the default definition of this function. Please check the readme.